# Difference between [object Object] and [object HtmlDivElement]. Div play with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

I am using divs like radio buttons and have a question.

I declare a function and variable like so

I have two styles set up, a .buttonUp and .buttonDown to be applied upon a div's onclick event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var onCheck;

function setRadio(param_ElementRef) 
{
    if (param_ElementRef != onCheck) 
    {
        if (onCheck) 
        {
            onCheck.className = 'buttonUp';
        }
        param_ElementRef.className = 'buttonDown';
        onCheck = param_ElementRef;
    }
}
</script>
```

I call a function in the div like this

```
<div id="Yes" class="buttonUp" onclick="setRadio(this)">Yes</div>
<div id="No" class="buttonUp" onclick="setRadio(this)">No</div>
<div id="Maybe" class="buttonUp" onclick="setRadio(this)">Maybe</div>
```

This works fine, but I'm having trouble setting a default value for the `onCheck` variable.

I have tried giving the divs id's, but when I `alert($('#Yes')` it displays `[object Object]`, whereas if I `alert(param_ElementRef)` it displays `[object HtmlDivElement]`

There is obviously a difference between the two, and is there a way of returning the same object by id reference or similar?

Many thanks

Comment: The reason `alert($('#Yes')` displays `[object Object]` is because it is a jQuery object.
On the other hand if you want `[object HtmlDivElement]` to be returned try `alert(document.getElementById('Yes'))` instead of `alert($('#Yes')`

Comment: Wow! Brilliant! Thank you. I was under the impression that $ and document.getElementbyId were one and the same. How wrong I have been! Thank you!

Comment: Posted the comment as an answer and also added something more

Comment: If you want to convert `[object HtmlDivElement]` or other HTML elements to `[object Object]` elements for JQuery use, wrap `$()` around the variable, like $(myHtmlVariable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `alert($('#Yes')` displays `[object Object]` is because it is a jQuery object.

On the other hand if you want `[object HtmlDivElement]` to be returned try `alert(document.getElementById('Yes'))` instead of `alert($('#Yes'))`

You can also get the plain js object from a jQuery object by using `get()`

for eg.
alert($('#Yes')) displays `[object Object]` and if you try `alert($('#Yes').get(0))` you will get `[object HtmlDivElement]`

Answer (score 2):

Add additional class to the div for the option

```
<div id="yes" class="button buttonUp">Yes</div>
<div id="no" class="button buttonUp">No</div>
<div id="maybe" class="button buttonUp">Maybe</div>
```

Here is jQuery code to select the option

```
var option;
$('.button').click(function() {
    option = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.selected').html('Your option - ' + option);
    $(this).addClass('buttonDown').removeClass('buttonUp');
});​
```

Check the example code in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prasofty/zWjjk/